# How to change Tree View icon from plus/minus to an arrow on Win 10?

Tags: windows-10, icons

I've accidentally changed my default tree view icons from these arrows:

[image]

to plus/minus icons:

[image]

How can I change them back? Thank you!

Comment: Try running a System Restore to an immediately prior point. Also, from an Admin Command Prompt, run dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  followed by SFC /SCANNOW  .  Restart when done and test.

Comment: Thank you, but neither of these 3 things helped. Maybe there's a registry key which should be reassigned to change the icons but I do not know if it exists or how to find it.

Comment: I am not sure how the defaults got changed, but if not of the above helped, the next step is a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.  Choose the second link, run in place, choose the option to Keep Everything when it comes up and this will normally fix most errors, update drivers and generally clean up:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Didn't work for me too. Both "Keep Everything" and the second option are grayed out for me and only a clean install can be chosen. I'll keep this option as a final solution though)

Comment: That is strange because I have done numerous Repair Installs successfully, so something must have gone wrong in the changes to prevent this. I assume you are using an Account with Admin Privileges to run the Repair. Otherwise if you can only do a clean install, then back up first and do that.